# Drawing Bitmap in Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to make a Simple Live wallpaper in which when user touch his screen a bitmap is drawn on that position. I am facing 2 problem, if i am drawing it in Runnable then it is continuously creating bitmaps and if i am drawing it outside then it continuously blinks. I have noticed that if i change my delay time for runnable blinking also changes and if i remove runnable completely then it is drawing fine but positions are getting weird.

Here is my code.
This one blinks continuously.

```
package com.example.live_wallpaper_p1;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;



public class DemoWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new DemoWallpaperEngine();
    }

    private class DemoWallpaperEngine extends Engine{
        private boolean mVisible = false;
        private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private Bitmap imm;
        private float xcor;
        private float ycor;
        BitmapFactory.Options option;       
        DemoWallpaperEngine()
        {
        imm = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon, option));
        }

        private final Runnable mUpdateDisplay = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            draw();
        }};

        @Override
        public Bundle onCommand(String action, int x, int y, int z, Bundle extras, boolean resultRequested) {
            if (action.equals(WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP)) {
                xcor=x;
                ycor=y;
                final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

                Canvas c = null;
                try {
                    c = holder.lockCanvas();
                    if (c != null) {
                    c.drawBitmap(imm, xcor-(imm.getWidth()/2), ycor-(imm.getHeight()/2),null);
                        //drawCube(c);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null)
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }

            }
            return null;
        }



        private void draw() {
           SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
           Canvas c = null;
           try {
              c = holder.lockCanvas();
              if (c != null) {
                  //do something
              }
           } finally {
              if (c != null)
                 holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
           }
           mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay); 
      if (mVisible) {
              mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateDisplay, 10); 

           } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            mVisible = visible;
            if (visible) {
                draw();
            } else {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
            }
        }

         @Override
          public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            draw();
          }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            mVisible = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
             super.onDestroy();
             mVisible = false;
             mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateDisplay);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The real effect is what you do in "draw()" or "render()" methods. You need to post that code here.

Comment: It is the full code. It is with draw() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample code

here imageURL is http link to Image Location

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
    holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If your Image is in Phone Memory.

use this

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.test2);
```

Comment: For this user will be needing Internet. I want my Bitmap inbuilt.

Comment: BitMap is Inbuilt Class in Java. I donno What you trying to say ?

Comment: The above code which you gave will require Internet Connection to operate. I want that it should work even if Internet connection is not available.

Comment: Then Where you save the Image in SDCard. ?

Comment: In the application itself. Like we save in other apps it is same for this.

Comment: then Use your Image Id to change the Image image.setImageResource(R.drawable.test2);

Comment: I know how to use image man. Problem is something else. Anyways thanks.

Comment: remove your c.drawBitmap from onCommand and past into draw() in place of comment"//do something"past it  and set the color black c.drawColor(Color.BLACK); in draw() and run